# Creating a Namespace In Lua Across Files

Tags: lua

If I want to have several files all in the same namespace/table, do I need to check if the table has already been defined? In otherwords for table:

```
TestNS = {}
```

Something like:

```
if(nil == TestNS) then
    TestNS = {}
end
```

I am new to Lua so if there is an alternative, let me know.

Comment: How are your files going to be loaded? If they can be loaded in any order (aren't using 5.1 `module` and `require`) and they expect to set a global then yes, that is more or less the right idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiom for that is

```
TestNS = TestNS or {}
```